# RAID-0 2х 256ГБ SSD, или достаточно одного SSD-512ГБ для большей производительности веб-сервера

Tags: mysql, сервер, веб-сервер, raid, ssd

Хочу арендовать выделенный сервер. На нем будет несколько баз данных под веб-приложения (PHP+MySQL).

Допустим в сумме базы данных будут занимать почти все пространство (~500ГБ).
MySQL будет обрабатывать множество запросов к этим БД, причем выборка из БД случайная (т.е. затрагиваться будут записи из разных областей диска).

Как будет лучше с точки зрения производительности: заказать один SSD размером 512ГБ, или заказать два SSD по 256ГБ и объединить их в RAID-0?

Comment: Во втором случае (256x2 RAID-0) у вас в два раза увеличится шанс потери данных

Comment: С точки зрения производительности конечно RAID-0 лучше. Но только зачем Вам это? Как известно, все компоненты системы должны быть сбалансированы. В Вашем случае это означает, что производительность канала связи должна быть сравнима с производительностью дисковой подсистемы. Если SSD RAID-0 стоит локально, то еще можно надеяться, что производительность SATA сравнима с производительностью самого диска. А если это удаленный сервер, то неужели у Вас канал к диску такой широкий, что производительность канала равна хотя бы производительности одного SSD  512? Вобщем считайте производительность.

Comment: Так сервер же выделенный будет. Память DDR4, процесссор I7-7700. Думается и канал связи с ssd будет достаточным

Comment: [Думается и канал связи с ssd будет достаточным] Тут не надо думать, тут надо выяснить у провайдера какой ширины канал связи и сравнить этот канал связи с производительностью SSD и SSD RAID-0. И еще учесть, что часто провайдеры обещают одно, а на деле у них канал как диалап 56 килобит. И еще вот что: у SSD чтение гораздо быстрее записи. Если у Вас с сервера будет в основном чтение, то со скоростью канала надо сравнивать именно скорость чтения SSD. Впрочем, если у Вас много записи на диск, то SSD ставить не рекомендуется. У SSD конечный ресурс по записи и Вам его быстро запилят до смерти.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду канал связи с "нешним миром"? 100мбит гарантия/1гбит shared

Comment: Да, именно, канал связи с внешним миром. Производительность этого канала должна быть сравнима с производительностью дисковой подсистемы. Если канал менее производительный чем диск, то значит Вы переплатили за диск. Если канал более производительный чем диск, то значит Вы переплатили за канал. И все это должно соответствовать потоку запросов. Если у Вас широкий канал но всего три запроса в день, то вы переплатили и за диск и за канал. Если у Вас 100500 запросов в день и узкий канал, значит Ваш сайт будет тормозить и лагать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. По циклам записи, ожидается около обновлений 2-5 млн  записей в день. Причем половина из них это счетчик одной и той же записи в БД, который будет с каждым запросом пользователя делать cnt=cnt+1.

Comment: Помилуйте, большинство серверов в нынешнем интернете имеют HDD в качестве хранилищ данных. Не нужен вам raid...

Comment: Если есть возможность использовать SSD в шине PCI-E (m2), то один драйв такого типа порвет RAID-массив SSD в шине SATA.

Answer (score 0):

> Вы имеете ввиду канал связи с "нешним миром"? 100мбит гарантия/1гбит
>   shared

Ну вот, теперь смотрим производительность SSD дисков.

> 60 ГБ SSD-накопитель DEXP S1 [SATA III, чтение - 300 Мбайт/с, запись -
>   270 Мбайт/с, Phison S3111-S11, MLC 2D NAND]
>
> 60 ГБ SSD-накопитель AFOX AFSN8T3BN60G [SATA III, чтение - 400
>   Мбайт/с, запись - 260 Мбайт/с, Silicon Motion SM2258XT, TLC 3D NAND]
>
> 120 ГБ SSD-накопитель Smartbuy Splash 3 [SB120GB-SPLH3-25SAT3] [SATA
>   III, чтение - 550 Мбайт/с, запись - 450 Мбайт/с, Marvell 88NV1120, TLC
>   3D NAND]

Чтение 300 Мбайт/с это грубо говоря 3000 Мбит/с. То есть 3Гбита/с. В три раза больше, чем Вам предлагает провайдер на пике производительности (да еще когда он это Вам выдаст, может и никогда, скажет что "нет технической возможности"). Да и "100мбит гарантия" зачастую на практике означает 50мбит максимум. То есть Вам нет никакого резона ставить  RAID-0, так как производительность и одного диска гораздо больше, чем производительность Вашего канала.

UPD1:

> По циклам записи, ожидается около обновлений 2-5 млн записей в день.

Смотря какого размера записи. Но вообще, правило такое:

1. Если у Вас проект типа библиотеки, когда Вы один раз заливаете на сервер информацию, а потом пользователи ее только читают, то можно ставить SSD диск (при условии, что потоки чтения настолько большие, и канал связи настолько широкий, что тормозит производительность именно диска).
2. Если у Вас проект типа youtube или инстаграмма, когда пользователи каждую секунду заливают Вам на сервер 100500 терабайт информации, то ставить SSD диск нет никакого смысла. Вам его запилят очень быстро, так как у SSD диска есть ограничение на количество записей.

UPD2:

А вообще-то выделенный сервер это довольно обязывающая вещь. Гораздо проще арендовать дисковое пространство и не заморачиваться техническими подробностями. А провайдер пусть сам следит и за балансом производительности, и за резервированием и за RAID-ами. Главное, выбрать нормального крупного провайдера с нормальной техподдержкой, а не пионеров из подвала. Впрочем, сейчас уже пионеров не осталось, всех съели.

UPD3:

> так пишите, как будто любое телодвижение от диска улетает обратно
>   пользователю по сети. Если субд потребуется прочитать всю таблицу на
>   полгига размером c диска, и отдать обратно 100 записей, это ведь не
>   потребует пропускания всех 500метров по сети, верно? – teran 1 минуту
>   назад

Ну это надо смотреть. Если у Вас база данных с поиском (типа продажи авиабилетов), то локальная производительность диска может быть важна. Но все равно, балансы производительности запросов по сети и производительности дисковой подсистемы никто не отменял.

Comment: так пишите, как будто любое телодвижение от диска улетает обратно пользователю по сети. Если субд потребуется прочитать всю таблицу на полгига размером c диска, и отдать обратно 100 записей, это ведь не потребует пропускания всех 500метров по сети, верно?

Comment: Благодарю. Выбрал в итоге вариант с одним SSD. А там буду мерить производительность, устроит или нет.

Comment: @Ruport планировать вперёд трудно. Причина в том, что человек — существо умное и всегда найдёт способ посрамить тупую железку. Я видел сайты, у которых формирование главной страницы занимало секунд десять, и всё это время машина проводила, ковыряясь в базе, а потом выдавала страничку на пятьсот килобайт с учётом картинок. И не потому что расчёты сложные, а потому что руки кривые. То есть смотрите: если у вас меньше ста HTTP-запросов в секунду, и при этом всё упирается в базу, то, скорее всего, проблема не в базе и не в дисках.